# Geofences shapes, API v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, maps, geofencing

reading the android and google maps Api v2, I've just found geofences defined by radius/circles.

I was wondering if there is a way to create custom shapes i.e. rectangles or any other irregular shapes.

I was planing to geofence the are of a park.

If custom shape geofencing is possible, please let me know the topics to study.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 3.1.36 there is only [`Geofence.Builder.setCircularRegion`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder.html#setCircularRegion%28double,%20double,%20float%29), so it's not possible to define other shapes, but the API looks like it could be extended easily in the future by the Location team in Google.

Comment: is there any alternative to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Custom shape geofencing certainly is possible but you must develop outside the API.
You could study:

- The best way to run a "heartbeat" schedule for your implementation
- Defining polygons as series' of coordinate pairs
- Choosing the preferred Location from android.location.LocationManager.getProviders()
- Determining whether a point lies within a given polygon or not